# Approximate function using non-orthogonal basis

Tags: approximation, projective-space

I'm currently trying to wrap my head around somebody's (very concise) description of Finite Element Analysis (FEA):

`When using FEA, your computed approximation (to the solution of some PDE) will simply be the projection of the exact solution onto your (finite dimensional) basis, in a piecewise (i.e. the domain divided into elements) fashion.`

When applying FEA, I just use a set of basis functions (e.g. the Lagrange polynomials), which aren't necessarily orthogonal nor of unit length (they might however form a partition of unity).

For illustrative purposes, let's use the non-orthogonal basis $\{1,x,x^2\}$ for $x \in [0,1]$, in which all quadratic polynomials on $[0,1]$ can be described. While it is quite trivial for this basis, the coefficients for an arbitrary quadratic polynomial in this space can be found using oblique projection (*not just simple orthogonal projection since our basis is not orthogonal*), as described in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148199/equation-for-non-orthogonal-projection-of-a-point-onto-two-vectors-representing).

**Actual Question:**

For a function that is **not** in this space of quadratic polynomials on $[0,1]$, for instance $\sin(\pi x)$, how is it projected onto this space (spanned by our non-orthogonal basis $\{1,x,x^2\}$)? Just to be sure, the projection of this function onto our basis is the *best approximation* possible, right?

So say the solution to something is in fact this function $\sin(\pi x)$, and we want to approximate it with some quadratic polynomial using the mentioned basis (the domain is $[0,1]$). What coefficients will I end up with?

**[Edit (1)]**: Any references to books that explain FEA from this perspective, or books in which this kind of projection is discussed, are most welcome!

**[Edit (2)]**: Is the best approximation in this case the same as the $L^2$ projection? An example would be very helpful.