# Non Orthogonal Non Negative Projection

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, numerical-methods

I am observing a system in which sampled points lie on some set of unknown conic polyhedrons in a d-dimensional space.  I have approximated the basis vectors of these conic polyhedrons and would like to transform my samples to be in terms of these vectors.  There is noise both in the observed sample points and in my approximations of the basis vectors.

Given n non-orthogonal, d-dimensional unit length basis vectors $v_1...v_n$ which define a conic polyhedron, and a d-dimensional sample point $x$, how can I find the n-dimensional transformed point $y=[a_1, a_2, ..., a_n]$ which minimizes ||$a_1v_1 + a_2v_2 + ... + a_nv_n - x||_1$ where $a_1 >= 0, a_2 >= 0, ..., a_n >= 0$

I am currently using Miguel's answer for non orthogonal projection in
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1123586/210629
but this can result in negative coefficients, as that question was about linear subspaces.  Is there a similar (ideally reasonably efficient) approach for conic polyhedrons/linear subspaces where coefficients are restricted to be non negative?

Additional notes:

- Because of noise in the measurements, I have trouble with numerical
  instability, especially when my estimates of basis vectors contain
  multiple near parallel basis vectors.
- My space is a taxicab geometry- can the solution also efficiently enforce that the L1 norms of x and y are equal or at least within some tolerance? $||x||_1 = ||y||_1$ or $| ||x||_1 - ||y||_1| < epsilon$

Comment: Non Negative Least Squares (NNLS) solves this iteratively for L2 norms.  I wonder if the problem if the problem isn't convex with L1 norms...  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.nnls.html

Comment: Ah, turns out NNLS maintains my desired constraints as long as all basis vectors are unit length!  NNLS is probably the right answer then